# Similarity between triangles; Double variables are a pain in the

Tags: c++, geometry

So, I have two classes, Point and Triangle, the latter having three Point members. I want to verify the similarity between two triangles.

This is the code that I came up with:

the Triangle.h:

```
class Triunghi
{
public:

Punct *A, *B, *C;
....
```

The Point.cpp:

```
double Point::distance(Point& a){
return sqrt((X - a.X)*(X - a.X) + (Y - a.Y)*(Y - a.Y));
}
```

the Triangle.cpp:

```
double Triangle::sideAB(){
return A->distance(*B);
}

//same thing for sideAC(), sideBC()

bool Triangle::similar(Triangle& tr){

double a[3] = { sideBC(),
    sideAC(), 
    sideAB() };
double b[3] = { tr.sideBC(),
    tr.sideAC(), 
    tr.sideAB() };

sort(a, a + 3);
sort(b, b + 3);

double aux1 = a[0] / b[0], aux2 = a[1] / b[1], aux3 = a[2] / b[2];

if (aux1 == aux2 && aux2 == aux3) return true;
return false;
}
```

The code works, but for:
triangle1: A(1,0) B(0,1) C(0,0)
triangle2: A(3,0) B(0,3) C(0,0)

it says that the triangles aren't similar. I know it's because I'm using double and whatnot.
I tried the multiplication way:

```
if(a[0]*b[1] == a[1]*b[0] && a[2]*b[1]==a[1]*b[2]) return true;
```

It doesn't work, same problem.
Also tried with comparing the angles; didn't work.

Any other ideas? I know I could use trunc() and I think it might work, but I want to know if there is a smarter way of doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: In the real world, coordinates aren't simple integer numbers, and what's more, they are inaccurate. You must learn to live with inaccurate data and practice error analysis. That said, the double data type provides far more accuracy than is needed for practical applications (except for very ill-posed problems, not the case here).

Answer (score 3):

Equality is generally not what you want to test when you're dealing with floating point values. In almost all cases, you care more about "approximately equal". While there is no "approximately equal" operator in C++, you can simulate it. You just need to see if if the values are *close enough*. See the example for [`std::numeric_limits::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 2):

As Joseph Mansfield describes above.  Use greater than or less than with the `std::numeric_limits::epsilon` found in `<limits>`.  As so:

```
double eps = std::numeric_limits::epsilon
if((std::fabs(a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]) < eps) && (std::fabs(a[2]*b[1] - a[1]*b[2]) < eps))
     return true;
```